# Unobvious behavior of the QMap().begin() function in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qmap

Let's look at the simple code with QMap iterator.

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QMap<int, QMap<int, int>> testA;
    testA [0][0] = 1;

    QMap<int,int>::iterator _iterTestA;

    for(_iterTestA = testA[1].begin(); _iterTestA!= testA[1].end(); _iterTestA++){
        qDebug()<<"Why am I working!? ";
    }

    qDebug()<<" testA " << testA;

}
```

***Expected behavior***

Code raise with some kind of  error when trying to set an iterator to a non-existence element of QMap.

***Real behavior***

Qt just creating an element testA[1] with an empty QMap() inside.

So output is:

```
testA  QMap((0, QMap((0, 1)))(1, QMap()))
```

What happening and why Qt is makes the decision for me?

Comment: Read the Qt manual. If the map contains no item with key key, the function inserts a default-constructed value into the map with key key, and returns a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is fully documented:

> [`T &QMap::operator[](const Key &key)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d)
>  Returns the value associated with
> the key key as a modifiable reference.
>
> **If the map contains no item with key key, the function inserts a
> default-constructed value into the map with key key, and returns a
> reference to it**. If the map contains multiple items with key key, this
> function returns a reference to the most recently inserted value.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Comment: Yes, you right, it's documented, but this behavior is completely illogical and can lead to unexpected errors. I cant remember any  examples of creating item with no assignment operator or creating function in other programming languages. Why Qt doesn't at least warn me? Why it work only with QMap an if you try to make it, for instance, with QVector, QList etc it will  cause an error, but not for QMAp.

Comment: @AleksandrKrasikov 1) It is not illogical since it is documented, and if you want to check if a map is valid or not then use the empty() method. 2) Qt avoids using exceptions as it consumes memory, read the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html

Comment: @AleksandrKrasikov And this is different from std::map?

Comment: @AleksandrKrasikov Recommendation: Always read the docs before pointing out that something is illogical because if the developer points out the behavior then you must adapt to that behavior, that is the dictatorship of the documentation. If you don't like it then implement your own container with your own "logical" behavior.